# How to avoid Apex cpu Limit Exceeded Error

Tags: apex

```
List<Account> accs=new List<Account>();
account a1=new account(name='gmail',phone='123');
account a2=new account(name='fb',phone='456');
account a3=new account(name='wtsup',phone='789');
accs.add(a1);
accs.add(a2);
accs.add(a3);

List<Contact> cons=new List<Contact>();
contact c1=new contact(LastName='gmail',phone='9030');
contact c2=new contact(LastName='fb',phone='7586');
contact c3=new contact(LastName='wtsup',phone='6935');
cons.add(c1);
cons.add(c2);
cons.add(c3);

insert accs;
for(account a:accs){
    for(contact c:cons){
        if(a.Name==c.LastName){
            c.AccountId=a.Id;
        }
    }
}
insert cons;
```

I am getting error apex cpu limit exceeded, can you plz help me to solve this problem....

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78407/discussion-on-question-by-rushda-shaik-how-to-avoid-apex-cpu-limit-exceeded-erro).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can leverage the following code to make it bulk safe and have it work for multiple records.

```
    List<Account> accs = new List<Account>();
    Map<String, Id> accNameIdMap = new Map<String, Id>();

    accs.add(new account(name='gmail',phone='123'));
    accs.add(new account(name='fb',phone='456'));
    accs.add(new account(name='wtsup',phone='789'));

    //Insert Accounts
    List<Database.SaveResult> saveResultList = Database.insert(accs);

    //Populate the accNameIdMap with key -> Name and value -> Id
    for(Account accRec :accs){
        accNameIdMap.put(accRec.Name, accRec.Id);
    }

    List<Contact> cons = new List<Contact>();
    cons.add(new contact(LastName='gmail',phone='9030'));
    cons.add(new contact(LastName='fb',phone='7586'));
    cons.add(new contact(LastName='wtsup',phone='6935'));

    if(accNameIdMap.size() > 0){

        for(Contact c :cons){

            if(accNameIdMap.containsKey(c.LastName)){
                c.AccountId = accNameIdMap.get(c.LastName);
            }
        }//for
    }

    //Insert Contacts
    List<Database.SaveResult> conSaveResultList = Database.insert(cons);
```

Comment: Why do you need to query name, when you just set that few lines above?

Comment: Hey, @Jigar,

After the Database.Insert method is run, you can access each Account's Id in the accs list.  No need for a SOQL query:   acct[0].Id will give you the first Account's Id.

Comment: Have updated the code and optimised it to exclude the Soql statement and the Set<Id> which was not required.